# which and type show different paths to IPython executable in virtualenv, import fails in IPython, succeeds in standard interpreter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, ipython, openstack-nova

```
(myvirtualenv)[~] sam@iota $ type ipython  
ipython is hashed (/usr/local/bin/ipython)  
(myvirtualenv)[~] sam@iota $ which ipython  
/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/ipython
```

#### regardless of what `which` says, it executes `/usr/local/bin/ipython`

```
(myvirtualenv)[~] sam@iota $ ipython
```

```
WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.  
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep  6 2013, 17:51:18)  

IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]:  import novaclient
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-93e5b70cb5b9> in <module>()
----> 1 import novaclient

/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/__init__.py in <module>()
     16
     17
---> 18 __version__ = pbr.version.VersionInfo('python-novaclient').version_string()

/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbr/version.pyc in version_string(self)
     70         if self.version is None:
     71             parts = []
---> 72             for part in self.release_string().split('.'):
     73                 if part[0].isdigit():
     74                     parts.append(part)

/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbr/version.pyc in release_string(self)
     62         
     63         if self.release is None:
---> 64             self.release = self._get_version_from_pkg_resources()
     65
     66         return self.release

/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbr/version.pyc in _get_version_from_pkg_resources(self)
     55             # installed into anything. Revert to setup-time logic.
     56             from pbr import packaging
---> 57             return packaging.get_version(self.package)
     58
     59     def release_string(self):

/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbr/packaging.pyc in get_version(package_name, pre_version)
    820     if version:
    821         return version
--> 822     raise Exception("Versioning for this project requires either an sdist"
    823                     " tarball, or access to an upstream git repository."
    824                     " Are you sure that git is installed?")

Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. Are you sure that git is installed?
```

#### now forcing it to execute `/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/ipython`

```
(myvirtualenv)[~] sam@iota $ `which ipython`
```

```
Python 2.7.5
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import novaclient
In [2]: print "all is well here"
all is well here
```

```
(myvirtualenv)[~] sam@iota $ echo $PATH
 /Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/lib:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
(myvirtualenv)[~] sam@iota $ python
```

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep  6 2013, 17:51:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.24)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import novaclient
>>> print "all is well here"
all is well here
>>> exit()
```

Why do `which` and `type` point to different paths? Why, if IPython is installed in my virtualenv, does the system IPython get executed, even though the order of my `$PATH` would indicate otherwise? In any case, why does `import novaclient` bomb out with what seems to be a pretty bizarre error?

---

### EDIT

### pythonpath from erroneous session

`(myvirtualenv)[~] sam@iota $ ipython -c 'import sys;sys.path'`

```
['/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

### pythonpath from successful session

`(myvirtualenv)[~] sam@iota $ python -c 'import sys;print sys.path'`

```
['',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/projectx-dev-2/bin',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/projectx-dev-2/src/pyrax',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/projectx-dev-2/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/projectx-dev-2/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/projectx-dev-2/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/projectx-dev-2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/projectx-dev-2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/projectx-dev-2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/projectx-dev-2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/projectx-dev-2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

Comment: This _might_ be a better question for a site like Super User, because I think ultimately the problem has nothing to do with virtualenv, or anything else but bash. But I'm not sure—there's no way of knowing that (either for the OP, or for a future searcher with a similar problem) until you actually know the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do which and type point to different paths?

If your shell has hashed `ipython`'s path, `type` will give you the hashed path without searching `$PATH`, while `which` will ignore the hashed path and do the search.

Assuming your shell is `bash`, the `hash` command (with no args) will show you the hashed paths, or you can look at the `BASH_CMDS` associative array. But you already know that `ipython` is hashed, because `type` just told you.

Usually you can fix this by just starting a new shell, using the `hash -r` command (to wipe the cache without restarting anything else), or `hash -d ipython` (to remove just `ipython` from the cache—but make sure you don't also have, e.g., `python` in the cache). With different shells, the two commands may be different (e.g., in *csh and zsh, it's `rehash` and `rehash ipython`, respectively), but starting a new shell should always works.

For more details, see the [Command Search and Execution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) in the bash reference manual, or the `bash(1)` manpage on your system, or the numerous easier-to-understand blog posts that will show up if you google something like "bash hash cache" (like [this one](http://bradconte.com/bash-path-hashing)).

> Why, if IPython is installed in my virtualenv, does the system IPython get executed

If your shell has hashed `ipython`'s path, `ipython` will run from the hashed path, without searching `$PATH`.

Again, starting a new shell, etc., should fix this.

> In any case, why does import novaclient bomb out with what seems to be a pretty bizarre error?

Most likely it's getting the `PYTHONPATH` from your environment, which causes the venv's site-packages and dist-packages to come become the system Python's, and the packages in those locations don't work with the system Python.

You can verify this by printing out `sys.path`. But the fact that it's complaining about files in `/Users/sam/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` implies that this path must be on `sys.path`. And (since you're running from a different directory) not just because the default `.` is picking it up, but because it's there explicitly. So, all that `sys.path` could tell you is whether it's an absolute or relative path.

Comment: great answer, thanks. what do you mean by `it must be happening`?

Comment: @smlstvnh: I mean that this path must be getting onto `sys.path` somehow. Rereading it, you're right, it's not very clear. I'll fix it, and thanks for pointing it out.